# mod_timer issue with linux kernel 4.18

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel, kernel

Having a problem with mod_timer function in linux kernel 4.18.   There is always a drift of around 10% ,  which causes synchronization issues in the driver.    Enclosed below a sample kernel module for a 100ms timer and the corresponding output with the delay of 10ms always.   CONFIG_HZ is set to 100 and the result is consistent with different HW.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>

#include <linux/gpio.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


void simple_timer_function(struct timer_list *);

struct timer_list simple_timer;
struct  timespec64 ts;

static int  __init simple_timer_module_init (void)
{
        timer_setup(&simple_timer,simple_timer_function,0);
        mod_timer(&simple_timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(100));
        printk(KERN_INFO" simple_timer_module_init init %ld\n",jiffies);
        return 0;
}

void simple_timer_function(struct timer_list *timer)
{

        printk(KERN_INFO" simple_timer_function Entry %d ms %ld \n",jiffies_to_msecs(jiffies),jiffies);
        ktime_get_ts64(&ts);
        printk(KERN_INFO" Timerfunction %llu.%09u seconds\n",(u64)ts.tv_sec, (u32)ts.tv_nsec);
        mod_timer(&simple_timer, (jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(100)));
}

static  void __exit simple_timer_module_exit (void)
{
        del_timer(&simple_timer);
}

module_init(simple_timer_module_init);
module_exit(simple_timer_module_exit);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 simple_timer_function Entry 64206210 ms 4301387917
 Timerfunction 64506.210291016 seconds
 simple_timer_function Entry 64206320 ms 4301387928
 Timerfunction 64506.320284514 seconds
 simple_timer_function Entry 64206430 ms 4301387939
 Timerfunction 64506.430298059 seconds
 simple_timer_function Entry 64206540 ms 4301387950
 Timerfunction 64506.540331204 seconds
 simple_timer_function Entry 64206650 ms 4301387961
 Timerfunction 64506.650281875 seconds
 simple_timer_function Entry 64206760 ms 4301387972
 Timerfunction 64506.760230434 seconds
 simple_timer_function Entry 64206870 ms 4301387983
 Timerfunction 64506.870294392 seconds
 simple_timer_function Entry 64206980 ms 4301387994
 Timerfunction 64506.980259710 seconds
 simple_timer_function Entry 64207090 ms 4301388005
 Timerfunction 64507.090272193 seconds
 simple_timer_function Entry 64207200 ms 4301388016
```

Any idea how to resolve it ?

Comment: The 10% is one jiffy. You could solve it by basing the `mod_timer` new expiry time on the previous expiry time instead of the current value of `jiffies`.

Comment: Time will never be less than what you requested and has a resolution of 10ms, so your result is expected.

Comment: For example, `simple_timer_function` could call `mod_timer(timer, timer->expires + msecs_to_jiffies(100));`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers...  In most of the kernel source code "mod_timer" is invoked with mod_timer(&timer_func, jiffies + DELAY), so does these delay have a drift? I read a similar answer in Linux kernel: Why add_timer() is modifying my "expires" value?.